# Error al dividir por cero

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class EjercicioCalcularPromedio30alumnos { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int edad = 0;
        int sumaedades = 0;
        float promedio = 0;

        for (int cantidad = 0; cantidad < 30; cantidad++) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Ingrese las notas de sus alumnos" + (cantidad + 1));
                edad = Integer.parseInt (bf.readLine());
            } while (!(edad > O));

            sumaedades = sumaedades + edad;
            promedio = sumaedades / cantidad;
        }

        System.out.println("su promedio es:" + promedio);
    }
}
```

El código no funciona, cuando hace 5 minutos funcionaba.

```
Ingrese la nota de sus alumnos1
3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at EjercicioCalcularPromedio30alumnos.main(EjercicioCalcularPromedio30alumnos.java:29)
C:\Users\se_ba\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Soy novato programando asi que pido paciencia porfavor :(

Comment: El error te lo dice. No puedes dividir por cero.

Comment: En la primera iteración del bucle la variable cantidad es 0, por ende la operación promedio = sumaedades / cantidad arrojará la exepción al dividir entre 0. Ten en cuenta que cuando haces (cantidad+1) en la linea 17 el valor de la variable cantidad no es incrementado, simplemente estás sumando 1 a la variable cantidad para ser utilizado en la operación de imprimir en consola. Para que la variable incremente en uno debes realizar una asignación: cantidad = cantidad +1, cantidad++ o cantidad+=1.

Comment: Hola Sebastian, te sugiero que leas [ask] para obtener información de cómo tu pregunta puede ser bien recibida por la comunidad (p.e. pon el código directamente en la pregunta en lugar de una captura de pantalla, explica qué es lo que realiza el código, y dónde estás recibiendo los errores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que cumple lo que buscas de una manera mas fácil

```
    public class Prueba {

    static Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int edad = 0;
        int acumulador = 0;

        System.out.println("Cuantas personas?");
        int cantidadPersonas = entrada.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadPersonas; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la edad de la persona N° " + (i+1));
            edad = entrada.nextInt();
            acumulador = acumulador + edad;
        }

        System.out.println("El promedio de la edad es : " + acumulador / cantidadPersonas);
    }

}
```

Tu error esta en que intentas dividir por cero en la primera iteracion del bucle. Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias se agradece la ayuda

Comment: Para eso estamos! Si no entiendes el código con gusto realizo anotaciones para que lo entiendas. Sigue adelante.

Comment: para que es el entrada.nextInt();??

Comment: Para obtener un dato numerico ingresado por teclado.